# mod_rewrite rules for Wordpress upload path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm converting a site over from Wordpress to a custom CMS and I'm trying to figure out how to handle all of the image paths that are within posts.

The URL structure is http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image-name.jpg

I need to get it in the form of http://site.com/uploads/image-name.jpg

This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([0-9-])/([0-9-])/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ uploads/$3 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't seem to be working though, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. You're middle to groupings only match a single digit or `-`. You need a `+` after them:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ /uploads/$3 [R=301,L]
```

And you'll want a slash before `uploads/` and you need to include a `.` as part of the final grouping (to match the extension).